# VBA Excel include a IF statement in email form

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to include a IF formula in my code, in the part where the email is being sent to some people included in column R2 of my Excel file

I would like to exclude from `.CC` the email `yyy@gmail.com` if this user is already in column R2 (so in `.To`). How could I write the code? Otherwise, my user `yyy@gmail.com` is receiving the email twice, once because the user is in `.To` and once because he is in `.CC`

```
.To = Worksheets("MyData").Range("R2").Value
.CC = "yyy@gmail.com; zzz@gmail.com; aaa@gmail.com"
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "TEST"
.Body = "Hello"
.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ME\" & Check & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy") & ".xlsx"
.Display
'.Send
```

What could be the code to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use an if statement for this. Instead I would remove each recipient from the cc line after setting both

```
.to = "yyy@gmail.com"
.cc = "yyy@gmail.com; zzz@gmail.com; aaa@gmail.com"
For Each addr In Split(.to, ";")
    .cc = Replace(.cc, addr, vbNullString)
Next addr
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "TEST"
.Body = "Hello"
.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ME\" & Check & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy") & ".xlsx"
.Display
```

The for loop splits the to line on the semi-colon character `;` and then loops through each one removing it from the `.cc` This will handle both single and multiple recipients in both the `.To` and `.CC` line

Comment: I propose to use `Replace(.cc, addr, vbNullString, , , vbTextCompare)` to catch upper/lowercase adresses also. After replacement there may remain some unnecessary spaces within the string, which could have been trimmed before, but that should be no problem with email adresses.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

```
If Worksheets("MyData").Range("R2").Value2 = "yyy@gmail.com" Then
    .CC = "zzz@gmail.com; aaa@gmail.com"
Else
    .CC = "yyy@gmail.com; zzz@gmail.com; aaa@gmail.com"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Replace` to remove the address in `.To` from your list in `.CC`

```
.To = Worksheets("MyData").Range("R2").Value
.CC = Replace("yyy@gmail.com; zzz@gmail.com; aaa@gmail.com", .To, vbNullString)
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer - it covers multiple recipients

Answer (score 0):

By this the addresses are trimmed and compared case insensitive:

```
    .To = Worksheets("MyData").Range("R2").Value
    .CC = ""
    Dim check As Variant
    For Each check In Split("yyy@gmail.com; zzz@gmail.com; aaa@gmail.com", ";")
        If Not InStr(1, .To, Trim(check), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then _
            .CC = .CC & "; " & check
    Next check
```