# Insert default signature after inserting a table of data from an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to insert a table of data from Sheet1 of my Excel workbook and my default signature.
I tried using HTMLBody but it displays the signature either before the table is displayed or nothing at all.
I tried changing the positions of the .HTMLBody.

I have to to send a mail of the below format:

- To:
- CC:
- BCC:
- Subject:
- Body: should contain "Hi Please find below the details"
- Then the Excel table with the data of range ("A3:F3)
- Then my signature (which is  the default signature in Outlook or something which could be created)
- and SEND.

The below is the code.

```
Sub esendtable()

Dim outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object

Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

With newEmail
    .To = "avc@123.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Data - " & Date
    .Body = "Please find below the data"
    .Display

    Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor
    Sheet1.Range("B3:F3").Copy

    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End =     
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
    .Display
    '.Send
    Set pageEditor = Nothing
    Set xInspect = Nothing
End With

Set newEmail = Nothing
Set outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considerd including it on the sheet with the table and moving it in one go?

Comment: Yes tried that. But it didn't work out.

Comment: How to add multiple email addresse into `To`, please see here for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54219147/10908769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
Sub esendtable()

Dim rng As Range
Dim Outlook As Object
Dim newEmail As Object
Dim SigString As String
Dim Signature As String
Dim xInspect As Object
Dim pageEditor As Object
Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:F3")
' You can also use a range with the following statement.
 Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("A3:F3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With


Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

SigString = "C:\Users\chipz\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\chipz_1.htm" ' Change chipz in path and signature file name

If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
Else
Signature = ""
End If

On Error Resume Next
With newEmail
    .To = "recipient@test.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Data - " & Date
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng) & "" & Signature

.Display
' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
' display the e-mail message.
'.Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With


Set newEmail = Nothing
Set Outlook = Nothing
Set newEmail = Nothing
Set Outlook = Nothing

End Sub
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Ron de Bruin 
' 
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```

Comment: Yes it works now.... Thank you so much. I am a newbie in this. So i was at crossroads with this. Tried a lot of things. Thanks you are a life saver.

Comment: Just one more quick question. how to add multiple addresses in the To list from an excel sheet?

Comment: @Chipz you will have to loop through cell range containing email addresses and concatenate with `;`. Please refer my recent post <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54914673/adding-email-function-to-excel-search/54930845#54930845> for more details. In case of some difficulty, please put up a new question.

Comment: Yes now it is working.i did not think about the concatenation. Thank you so much.!!!! you really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your email's body by

> Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem).GetInspector.WordEditor.Range

So following simple code snippet

- preserves the standard signature for a new email
- pastes the Excel range as range, picture or plain text
- adds text before Excel range and/or between it and signature

---

```
With pageEditor.Range
    .Collapse 1   ' wdCollapseStart
    .InsertBefore "Hi Please find below the details" & vbCrLf
    .Collapse 0   ' wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter "Text before signature" & vbCrLf
    .Collapse 1   ' wdCollapseStart

    Sheet1.Range("B3:F3").Copy
    .Paste
    '.PasteAndFormat 13  ' wdChartPicture
    '.PasteAndFormat 22  ' wdFormatPlainText
End With
```

If you add a reference to "Microsoft Word x.x Object Library" (and "Microsoft Outlook x.x Object Library") for early binding, you can replace the numbers by the corresponding Word ENUM constants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my code as below

```
Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

With newEmail
.display
signature = newEmail.HTMLBody
sig = HtmlToText(signature)

.To = ""
.CC = ""
.Subject = "Test"
.HTMLBody = "Dear team," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Please check and fix the issue below. Thank you!"

Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

wb.Sheets(1).Range("a1:h" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.body)
pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdformatplaintext)
.display

.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & signature
Set pageEditor = Nothing
Set xInspect = Nothing

End With
```